# Connection refused when trying to connect to bluetooth server

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a simple Bluetooth client / server where my Raspberry Pi is the server and my laptop the client.

This is the server code (running on my Raspberry Pi):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8

import wifi, bluetooth

uuid="1e0ca4ea-299d-4335-93eb-27fcfe7fa848"

print "Setting up Bluetooth socket"

try:
  sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
  sock.bind(("", 0))
  sock.listen(1)
except IOError as e:
  print str(e)


print "Registering service"
try:
  bluetooth.advertise_service(sock, "MyService", uuid)

  while True:
    print "Waiting for connection..."  
    client_sock,address = sock.accept()
    print "Accepted connection from {0}".format(address)

    data = client_sock.recv(1024)
    print "Received data: {0}".format(data)

    print "Closing client socket."
    client_sock.close()
except IOError as e:
  print str(e)
```

This seems to work, the script runs and blocks with `Waiting for connection...`.

Then, my client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8

import bluetooth, time

mac = "00:15:83:E5:E2:46"
uuid = "1e0ca4ea-299d-4335-93eb-27fcfe7fa848"

service = []
retry = 1
while len(service) == 0:
  print "Looking for service on {0}, try {1}".format(mac, retry)
  service = bluetooth.find_service(address=mac, uuid=uuid)
  retry = retry + 1
  time.sleep(1)

if len(service) == 1: 
  service = service[0]
  print "Service found. Name={0}".format(service["name"])

  print "Connecting to service."

  sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
  try:
    sock.connect((mac, service["port"]))
    print "Connected to service on {0} on port {1}".format(mac, service["port"])
  except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as e:
    print "Connection failed: {0}".format(e)

elif len(service) == 0:
  print "No service found on mac {0}.".format(mac)
else:
  print "{0} services found for mac/uuid, ignored.".format(len(service))
```

Also works, up until I try to `connect()` to the Raspberry Pi. I get the following error:

```
Connecting to service.
Connection failed: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

I tried connecting the laptop to the Raspberry Pi (it finds it and says it is "Connected") and searching for more info online, but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occures when u want to connect to not listening port.

U are listening on port "0" .....
Change it to for example 9999 and then client has to connect to that port on the server adress

Comment: The [documentation](https://pybluez.googlecode.com/svn/www/docs-0.7/public/bluetooth-module.html#get_available_port) says: `deprecated. bind to port zero instead. `. Also, when requesting the service, it says it is running on port 1. When choosing a different port, I get a different error.

Comment: Yet another example of vague documentation. Taking a port explicitly did work. Port 1 didn't work though.